# Any way to disable or delay Windows 7 Shutdown window

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Win 7 and Vista have that window that pops up when programs are blocking shutdown after 5 seconds. It's the one with the Force Shutdown and Cancel buttons.

Is there a way to disable this screen? or at least increase the time before it occurs?

Comment: Disable would mean force shutdown. It onlz stucks there if somthing prevents it. So if you increase time you are at the exact same place. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I've had this problem too. When a program asks you something before shutdown - like a "don't you want to save your data?" dialog - the screen still comes and you cannot click either Yes or No, but have to terminate the program before shutdown continues. There is no way to save the data if you forgot to do it before initiating shutdown. So if somebody knows a solution, please post it, it'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run "regedit"

open this location
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control

change value of this key "WaitToKillServiceTimeout" between 2000-20000ms, where 2000 = 2sec.

Comment: This setting doesn't apply to Win7

Comment: Its working 100% on windows 7 check out the screenshots as well http://www.trickyways.com/2010/07/speed-up-shut-down-time-windows-7/